# Entity Framework Model First Self referencing

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, self-reference

I have seen a bunch of code first examples, but not model first.

I want to create a Parent - Child relationship where ParentId is nullable, and if a Category is a really a SubCategory, it would have a ParentId.

When I did this via the designer, it ended up generating this...which looks opposite of what I was trying to create:

```
public partial class Category : NWatchObjectBase
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
        this.Parent = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    public int Handle { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual CasModelClass ModelClass { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Child { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I also cannot find anything about this using model first; not even this, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this. EF should handle this gracefully.

```
public partial class Category : NWatchObjectBase
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
        this.Children = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    public int Handle { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual CasModelClass ModelClass { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to update the diagram and every time I save my solution, it will revert to what I pasted above.

Comment: I was misinterpreting the designer, and I got it right now!  Thanks for your help!